# How to upload image to Amazon S3 using the AmazonS3 module?

Tags: media

I installed the AmazonS3 module, and I have the option to upload an image to AmazonS3: (screenshot of image field settings below)
[image]

Is it related to configurations under admin/config/media/file-system? If so what value should I put in Public File System to save files directly to Amazon S3?

I already tried the following: *s3://* but it didn't work.
I am using the AmazonS3 module: https://drupal.org/project/amazons3

[image]